# How to make an ESP32 S2 not lose USB connection after uploading?

Tags: arduino, usb, serial, esp32, reset

I am using an ESP32 S2 Mini, and I'm running into this problem:

1. I put the unit into the "flash" state, by pressing the "0" and "RST" buttons. Doing this establishes the USB connection, I can hear a sound, and select the "Port" in the Arduino IDE.
2. I upload my sketch, but in the end I am getting an error, that the board cannot be reset via the USB connection. I've read that would be expected though.
3. In order to reset the unit and start my program, I press the "RST" button once more.
4. However, this interrupts the USB connection, i.e. the "Port" in the Arduino-IDE is greyed out, and I cannot open the "Serial Monitor" to debug my program.

Is there anything I could do about this?

Comment: I think this happens because the USB is reset while the serial port is opened in Arduino IDE. You can try disconnecting the serial port from the IDE before pressing the RST and then connecting it again afterwards.

Comment: @rodrigo How to do that exactly? If I unplug, and replug, the controller is reset, but I can only connect the Port in Arduino, if the controller is in "flash" mode, at least that's my observation.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't remember the details of a similar thing that happened to me some time ago. I think that I used to select "Tools / Port" and a different unrelated port. Then do the reset, wait for a few seconds and select "Tools / Port" and the right port, and think it reconnected the console output.